# "Object expected" error on calling RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

This is a little weird.

I have the following scenario:

A page containing a usercontrol - used for popup. This usercontrol has a placeholder, so I can dynamically load any usercontrol inside this popup. This works great - and all inside ajax updatepanels.

Inside one of the dynamically loaded usercontrols I have a jscript declared as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setup(){
    alert("test");
}
</script>
```

And in the codebehind I have a method with this in it:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "setup" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "setup();", true);
```

The reason I have a Guid thrown in there, is so it won't bug me, if I call the method more than once.

Now, this method is hooked up to a button. This works GREAT in firefox. But in IE8 it gives me this js error:

"Object expected" on line 197910701 char 1

So I can't even debug it, since obviously that line doesn't exist - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just getting the same error and was hoping to find the answer here.  After a little more investigating, the problem (for me) was a simple one ... **the javascript function** i was trying to call in my server generated "<script>" tag **did not exist** (it was miss-typed).  I am assuming you are past this problem since it's two months later, but it may be useful if anyone else stumbles across this.

Comment: I actually abandoned asp.net entirely for MVC3. Not just because of this though :) But nice of you to answer

Answer (score 0):

Another cause to this might be that the function is defined after the  ending tag.
In order for `RegisterStartupScript` to work properly (and find the javascript function), the function has to be defined before the form tags or inside of them, but NOT after the  ending tag (otherwise an Object expected error will occur).